# How do I verify an alert dialog has appeared using mockingjay in a widget test?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Using the [mockingjay](https://pub.dev/packages/mockingjay) Flutter package, how do I verify in a widget test that an alert dialog has been displayed after e.g. tapping a button? The alert dialog is displayed using the showDialog function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very similar to verifying page navigation behaviour, the thing that caught me out was the showDialog function must have the parameter `useRootNavigator` set to false, as documented in the [example project](https://github.com/VeryGoodOpenSource/mockingjay/blob/37d8e5a2ae59ce9778ca4cf734dc6928220ea747/example/lib/ui/quiz_dialog.dart#L15). Without it the test will fail to detect that the alert dialog was displayed.

```
showDialog(
   context: context,
   useRootNavigator: false, // By default this is true, which won't work with Mockingjay
   routeSettings: RouteSettings(name: 'verify_checkout_failure'),
   builder: (context) {
       return AlertDialog(title: Text('Checkout failed'));
   });
```

Then in your test:

```
await tester.tap(find.byType(PlaceOrderButton));

  verify(
    () => mockNavigator.push(
      any(
        that: isRoute<void>(
          whereName: equals('verify_checkout_failure'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```